# Pattern match on a data family in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching, gadt, type-families

I have wrapped up whole data family in a single existential:

```
data Type = Numeric | Boolean 

data family Operator (t :: Type)
data instance Operator 'Numeric = Add | Sub
data instance Operator 'Boolean = And | Or

data AnyOp where
  AnyOp :: Operator t -> AnyOp
```

Now I would like to do some pattern matching on it

```
pp :: AnyOp -> String
pp op = case op of
  AnyOp Add -> "+"
  AnyOp Sub -> "-"
  AnyOp And -> "&"
  AnyOp Or  -> "|"
```

But the typechecker yells at me because

> ````
>       ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>         a pattern with constructor:
>           AnyOp :: forall (t :: TType). Operator t -> AnyOp,
>         in a case alternative
>         at somesource/somefile/someposition
>       Expected type: Operator t
>         Actual type: Operator 'Boolean ```
> ````

Why? What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the error you get?

Comment: Sure, have just done it

Comment: You need a singleton `data AnyOp where  AnyOp :: SType t -> Operator t -> AnyOp` and `data SType t where SNumeric :: SType 'Numeric ; SBoolean :: STYpe 'Boolean`. You should find many examples of singletons in Haskell GADTs in you search for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a distance, data families look a little like GADTs, in that two constructors for a data family can produce results of different types. But data families are not the same as GADTs! They're really much more like type families. You can't actually match on `Add` or `Sub` until you know that you have an `Operator 'Numeric`. Why is this? You can think of it operationally. Each constructor has to have a "tag" so that `case` expressions can distinguish them. If two Data instances are defined in different modules, then they may well end up using the same tag for different constructors! Furthermore, a newtype instance doesn't even get a tag, so there's no way to distinguish them at all! As chi indicates, you can work around this by wrapping up a singleton in your existential to keep track of which data instance you have.

---

My understanding is that data families don't really offer much, if any, power that can't be obtained without them. Let's see how a data family slightly more complex than yours can be expressed, very awkwardly, with a newtype, a type family, and pattern synonyms.

```
import Data.Kind (Type)

data Typ = Numeric Bool | Boolean

newtype Operator t = Operator (OperatorF t)

type family OperatorF (t :: Typ) :: Type

type instance OperatorF ('Numeric b) = OpNum b
type instance OperatorF 'Boolean = OpBool

-- This makes no sense; it's just for demonstration
-- purposes.
data OpNum b where
  Add' :: OpNum 'True
  Sub' :: OpNum 'False

data OpBool = And' | Or'

pattern Add :: () => (b ~ 'True) => Operator ('Numeric b)
pattern Add = Operator Add'

pattern Sub :: () => (b ~ 'False) => Operator ('Numeric b)
pattern Sub = Operator Sub'

pattern And :: Operator 'Boolean
pattern And = Operator And'

pattern Or :: Operator 'Boolean
pattern Or = Operator Or'
```